# How much does inventory increase when you upgrade a floor's rank?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have upgraded a few floors but only a few times.   It seems to get rather expensive quickly in towerbux, but 
how much does inventory increase per rank? Is there a formula that I can adhere to?

Comment: *Basically I want to see if it's worth it to upgrade low inventory levels so I don't have to restock them so frequently.  If the cost goes goes up + 1 towerbux per rank but the inventory increases the same amount per level, I don't think it's worth it - but that's just my opinion*

Comment: I never pay Bux to upgrade. Too expensive. Just wait for the upgrader VIP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inventory increases by 10% of the **base** amount per upgrade rank.

That is, if at rank 1 a non-dream-job worker would stock 100 of an item, every upgrade rank increases the amount they stock by 10. Thus at rank two they'll stock 110, at rank three 120, at rank four 130, etc. The dream job bonus is applied *after* rank bonus, so if that was the worker's dream job they'd stock 200 at rank one, 220 at rank two, 240 at rank three, etc.

It's generally best to focus on the stores that have the most inventory (after factoring in dream job bonuses).